# How can I duplicate my component in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<template>
  <!--This is my main file -->
  <div id="inputs">
    <h1>언어 관리</h1>
    <v-btn color="primary" elevation="10" large @click="duplicateEl"
      >Add row</v-btn
    >
    <Contents />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Contents from "./Contents.vue";
export default {
  name: "LanguageMainMenu",
  components: { Contents },
  methods: {
    duplicateEl() {
      alert("You can duplicate buttons");
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style>
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 38px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I just need function to make component duplicate thanks!!

Comment: Donot paste the screenshot of the code. Instead paste the code itself

Comment: <template> <!--This is my main file -->
<div id="inputs">
<h1>언어 관리</h1>
   <v-btn color="primary" elevation="10" large @click="duplicateEl">Add row</v-btn>
 <Contents/>
 
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Contents from './Contents.vue'
export default {
    name:"LanguageMainMenu",
  components:{ Contents },
  methods:{
    duplicateEl()
    {
      alert("You can duplicate buttons")
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
h1
{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:38px;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin:auto;
} 

</style>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best apprach is to use the component inside `v-for`.

Increment the index when the button is clicked.

Dont forget to use `key` inside the `v-for`

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: "LanguageMainMenu",
  components: {
    Contents: {
      template: `<div>Contents Component</div>`,
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      totalCount: 1,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    duplicateEl() {
      this.totalCount++;
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <!--This is my main file -->
    <div id="inputs">
      <h1>언어 관리</h1>
      <button @click="duplicateEl">Add row</button>
      <Contents v-for="count in totalCount" :key="`component-${count}`" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did as you said but still  the component appears just once. I'm beginner for Vue hope u  understand thanks!

Comment: Click the `Add row` button. Can you check the above fiddle? Its working as you said

Comment: I'm in development environment of project, there was an error with template when I was running

Comment: The overall implementation of the code is with this logic itself. Fixt the template error and try to integrate this logic in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property in data object and use v-for for render buttons.
Let method duplicateEl to change the property value.

```
<v-btn v-for="item in btnNumber" ....>
```

```
duplicateEl(){
  this.btnNumber++
}
```